Why did I observe a yellow ring around filter paper after filtering Cu out of CuCl2 + Al reaction?
I reacted 0.40 M CuCl2 with 0.50 g of granular Al.  After waiting for the reaction to be complete I filtered out the copper.  After allowing the filter paper to sit to dry overnight, I observed the copper and it was surrounded by a green color that I expected after the copper oxidized.  What I didn't expect was a yellow ring about 2-3 mm in width at the outer edge of the entire filter paper.  What would the yellow ring be made of or made from?

The yellow ring at the outer edge of the filter paper is probably due to some ferric compound like $\ce{FeCl3}$ or $\ce{Fe(OH)_nCl_{3-n}}$. Ferric compounds are usually brown and intensely colored. Their origin is probably an impurity in the metal aluminium : it is rather difficult to remove the last proportion of iron in even pure aluminium samples. Usually pure aluminium contains traces of iron (and other elements like $\ce{Si}$ and $\ce{Mn}$). As iron $\ce{Fe}$ and aluminium $\ce{Al}$ react the same way with $\ce{CuCl2}$, this reaction produces first $\ce{Cu}$ plus $\ce{Fe^{2+}}$ ions. But in the presence of air, this $\ce{Fe^{2+}}$ion is easily oxidized into brown ferric ion $\ce{[Fe(OH)]^{2+}}$  by $\ce{O2}$
according to :$$\ce{4Fe^{2+} + O2 + 2H2O -> 4[Fe(OH)]^{2+}}$$
In non-acidic water this ion is quickly hydrolyzed and produces a precipitate $\ce{Fe(OH)3}$ or $\ce{[FeO(OH)]}$ in a reaction like $$\ce{[Fe(OH)]^{2+} + 4 H2O -> Fe(OH)3 + 2 H3O+}$$
$$\ce{[Fe(OH)]^{2+} + 3 H2O -> FeOOH +  2 H3O+}$$ But in presence  of $\ce{Al^{3+}}$ in solution, the solution becomes acidic due to hydrolysis of $\ce{Al^{3+}}$ and the precipitation of $\ce{Fe(OH)3}$ does not occur
